# How to change style of R-output-box in RMarkdown

Tags: css, r-markdown

I would like to change the backgroundcolor of the code-output-box (where the results of my R calls are shown) in RMarkdown for html using css.

I know how to change the color of the code-box, with eg.

```
pre.sourceCode { background-color: rgb(204, 255 , 204); }
```

But how do I reference the output-box?
If I use just `pre {}`, nothing changes in my output document...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/chunk-styling.html

You can refer to code- and output-box via `class.source` and `class.output`

In the css-file, create a new class `foobar` containing your desired styling, e.g.

```
.foobar {
background-color: rgb(100, 0, 0);
}
```

Refer to `foobar` within an `r`-chunk with

````
```{r class.output="foobar"}
# some r code
```
````

If you want to set `class.output="foobar"` as default, add to the YAML header

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, class.output="foobar")
```

Keep in mind, that there are some pre-defined classes ready for use, try out "`bg-primary`", "`bg-success`", "`bg-info`", "`bg-warning`", and "`bg-danger`"

Comment: This was exactly the link I was going to send when reading the question. Rmarkdown cookbook is definitely great!